# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using ARC and can't track on simulator

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, exc-bad-access

I have been building an app for a client and everything was going smoothly until I started getting this error.  This is a unique situation, I've learned how to use instruments and NSZombie however I can't run instruments with NSZombieEnabled on the iPhone only on the simulator.  I have to debug this problem in the iPhone because I'm using UIImagePicker to take a picture and the error happens shortly after I take the picture.  I'm also using ARC so I can't set release or retain info at all, ARC forbids it, so I doubt its a double release or anything like that.  There are 2 possible answers to this question.

1:  Does anyone know if I can pass an image into UIImagePicker using photo booth?  I could use instruments and NSZombie if I could get passes the camera screen.

2:  Is there a way to detect what line would be causing the error without refactoring or commenting out code using the iPhone?  Does anybody know an efficient way to track down bad_acces on the iPhone?

Keep in mind I am using ARC and cannot debug this on the simulator.  If I take out the UIImagePicker control script the bug does not happen so I've narrowed it down to something in my CameraViewController class.  I'm afraid I can't post any code due to a preexisting contract, you would have to be an employee to view source code.

Sorry about the limited information but really I'm looking for an answer about debugging not a direct solution to my exact code problem.

Going to post the backtrace(i think)

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x339737e4 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x31b30140 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#2  0x31b300e0 in -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] ()
#3  0x31b300b2 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#4  0x31b2fe04 in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#5  0x31b30452 in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#6  0x31b2eddc in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#7  0x31b2e756 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#8  0x31b299fe in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#9  0x31b29336 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#10 0x3026c04a in PurpleEventCallback ()
#11 0x3443fce2 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#12 0x3443fca6 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#13 0x3443256c in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#14 0x34432276 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#15 0x3443217e in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#16 0x3026b5f2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#17 0x3026b69e in GSEventRun ()
#18 0x31ad0122 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#19 0x31ace12e in UIApplicationMain ()
#20 0x000034ce in main (argc=1, argv=0x2ffff75c) at /Users/Andrew/Documents/Developing/Xcode Projects/ProjectSVN/Project/trunk/ProjectInterface/ProjectInterface/main.m:16
```

Comment: On the simulator can you (temporarily) change your code to pick from the photo gallery instead - you should be able to debug on it then (that would also help narrow down where your bug is :)

Comment: It opens up the photo gallery in place of the camera on the simulator, how can I add a photo to it?

Comment: Drag an image onto the simulator - this will open in Safari. long press on the image and you get the option to save it.

Comment: Ah that is really cool!  I'm dragging the image, and I click save and switch back to the app and the saved photo isn't appearing in photo gallery for some reason.

Comment: Oh, it should appear in the 'Saved Photos' gallery :( It does on my simulator at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code samples it is hard to say, however ARC doesn't totally cover all of your bases. For example, it is possible to get these EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors when objects (classes with delegates) do not exist, yet try to execute callback delegate methods.

To be more specific, let's say I have created a class in `viewDidLoad:` - let's call it `ClassA`. In my hypothetical situation, I set my view controller to `ClassA`'s delegate. However, I have not declared a property for `ClassA`, so there is no reference to it beyond the scope of `viewDidLoad:`.

Now let's assume `ClassA` declare a delegate method that is implemented by my view controller. This delegate passes a reference of itself back to the view controller in this delegate method. Because it may or may not be out of scope by this point, BOOM, bad access error. Check for things such as this, where objects do not exist anymore and are being passed to other methods - it is one such way ARC can fail you ;)

Comment: This sounds really close to my problem, I am brand new to xCode so I'm still pretty inexperienced.  I do alloc a pointer to an object and pass to 3 separate classes consecutively.  Maybe it is because the class that allocated the pointer gets released and the pointer becomes corrupted?  Can I pass the actual object and not the pointer?

Comment: I doubt that. If the delegate wasn't hooked up it probably wouldn't crash, there would just be no callback functionality. Make sure when you are passing an object to many places that it persists beyond the method it is doing this in.

Comment: Alright that was actually the exact problem, being new to xCode I had initialized like 5 different classes without property's in a method in my viewController.  All I did was add the properties for the classes and Booyah!  Thanks everyone for helping me, learned quite a bit from this post.

Answer (score 2):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` doesn't necessarily mean a memory management problem.  It could just as easily be caused by memory corruption or other kinds of errors.

Post the backtrace of the crash.

Comment: I am really new to xCode where can I grab the backtrace in xCode 4.2?  Sorry I'm still a junior in my CS degree and have been writing in objective c for less than a month.

Comment: No worries; we were all there once (or twice).  When your app crashes, you should be dropped to the debugger prompt in Xcode. Type 'bt<return>' and paste the output into your question as code.

Comment: heh, the first time I actually typed <return> D'OH!