# iOS - EXC_BAD_ACCESS - How can it happen under ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

In my current project, I'm getting exc_bad_access randomly, but always on the same line of code (when returning a NSNumber object from a method).

The question is, how is it even possible that exc_bad_access is happening under ARC?

I'm not using any unsafe_unretained pointers or similar things.

The first answer on this thread seems to explain one possible cause of these errors, but unfortunately, I don't quite understand the setup:

[EXC_BAD_ACCESS using ARC and can't track on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583570/exc-bad-access-using-arc-and-cant-track-on-simulator)

The interface of the class that has getImageVersion in it:

```
@interface PhotoFetcher : NSObject {

NSMutableData *photoData;
NSString *photoNick;

NSNumber *imageVersion; // <---- Strong ivar

PhotoSize photoSize;
}
```

Here's the crashing method:

```
- (int)getImageVersion:(NSString *)nick
{
if (nick && !imageVersion)
{
    imageVersion = [[RuntimeData sharedData].nickImageVersionCache imageVersionForNick:nick];
    if (!imageVersion)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[RuntimeData sharedData].knuddelsDataStore managedObjectContext];

        [context performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSFetchRequest *userRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ConversationUser"];
            userRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nickname = [c] %@", nick];
            userRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"imageVersion"];
            userRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
            userRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

            NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:userRequest error:nil];
            if (objects.count > 0)
            {
                NSDictionary *dict = objects[0];

                imageVersion = dict[@"imageVersion"];

                [[RuntimeData sharedData].nickImageVersionCache setImageVersion:imageVersion forNick:nick];
            }
        }];
    }
}
return imageVersion.intValue; // <<<<----- Line of Crash, exc_bad_access
}
```

That's the Stacktrace:

[image: Stacktrace]

Comment: Is this Swift or ObjC? Are you using Core Data?

Comment: Hi, Can you attach stack trace?

Comment: Is the nsnumber property you are accessing part of a NSManagedObject subclass?

Comment: @Sajjon, it's part of a dict, that was part of an array, that is fetched from NSManagedObjectContext. Then it's stored locally, but not copied.

Comment: Added code and Stacktrace.

Comment: And have you checked that `imageVersion` is not a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: How do you mean? It should be either nil or NSNumber, either way it shouldn't crash with exc_bad_access.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, every object can be nil.

Since you are getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to access a property on your NSManagedObject I would say that you maybe have forgotten to check "optional" in the Core Data model for that attribute. I guess you are converting JSON from some backend server into Core Data objects? Maybe the JSON value for said attribute it null.

When using Core Data, if you get a null value inserted in to a variable that has not the "optional" flag checked, you well get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing the variable if it is null.

Comment: But I'm not accessing the NSManagedObject directly. Are you sure this could be the cause? (I'm just trying to find out how to make attributed optional, to test what you say)

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, this happens when I call a method or property that doesn't exist. In other words, if ImageVersion is nil, it doesn't have an intValue.

You should check this in your code.

Comment: If imageVersion is nil, it will not crash due to the Objective-C Runtime checking for nil before trying to access intValue. In the case of it being nil, 0 will be returned.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is caused by dereferencing an invalid pointer, not by calling a nonexistent method, which would instead result in an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Ah oke, sorry for misunderstanding and thanks for explaining! Now that I think of it, I did in fact have IllegalArgumentException in mind..